# How to directly open a specific preference in the preferences activity?

Tags: android

I want to know if there is any way to launch my preference activity in my Android app and have it open/click on a specific preference automatically for editing.

Answer (score 0):

here list of settings flags http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html    for example you can start wireless settings activity    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

Comment: Aren't those for standard Android settings? What if I have my own preference activity? Can I create my own setting flag?

Comment: if you have your own settings you can provide any access to them in you application you are not needed in android features and flags.